# Query that finds the oldest driver

Tags: ms-access

Given two tables:

`driver=(`**`d_id`**`,name,gender,birthday,address,country)`

`event_list=(`**`o_id,d_id`**`,odate,oplace)`

The `event list` table represent the driving violations of the driver , o_id is the violation number(id), d_id is the driver id, odate is the date of the violation

The `driver` table represent the driver details, the birthday is the year of the birth e.g `1992`

> Write query that finds the name and the birth yaer  of the oldest driver that have made at least one violation that lives in Haifa

---

**My attempt:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, birthday 
FROM driver INNER JOIN event_list ON driver.d_id=event_list.d_id
GROUP BY  name, birthday,address  
HAVING MIN(birthday) AND driver.address='haifa';
```

I have a problem with the minimum, the output is all the drivers that have made at least one violation that living in Haifa, but **all** of them, not the oldest one, how can I improve my code? I need only the oldest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 name, birthday    
FROM driver 
INNER JOIN event_list ON driver.d_id=event_list.d_id
WHERE driver.address='haifa'
ORDER BY birthday;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tricky around the oldest driver but I'll have a go:

```
SELECT name, birthday 
FROM driver 
WHERE name in (SELECT name FROM driver where driver.address = 'haifa')
AND  d.id in (SELECT d.id FROM event_list)
AND birthday = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(birthday)
                FROM driver  
                WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM driver WHERE driver.address =  'haifa') AND  d.id in (SELECT d.id from event_list))
```